# Hitting time of a discrete time supermartingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, martingales

Say $M_t$ is a discrete time supermartingale on $\mathbb{R}$, with $M_0 > 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[M_t | \mathscr{F}_{t-1}] \leq M_{t-1} - \alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$. Let $\tau := \min(t : M_t <0)$. We want to know
$\mathbb{E}[\tau]$.

I know how to handle this when $M_t$ is something like a Brownian motion with drift, but I wonder if we can say anything in the discrete time case?

Thank you --

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make the question more specific for it to have an answer.

If all you know is that $\mathbb E[M_t | \mathscr F_{t-1}] \leq M_{t-1} - \alpha$, then this is too permissive to be able to say anything concrete. (Consider two deterministic walks that each start at $10$; one takes a step downward at each time increment, and the other takes a half-step downward at each time increment. Both satisfy the supermartingale condition with $\alpha = 0.1$, for instance.)

The inequality is the issue here more than the $\alpha$. The reason that you're able to do anything concrete with Brownian motion with drift isn't that it's a sub/super-martingale, it's that you can add something convenient to it to get it to become a martingale. That's the level of specificity you'd want to have here. If your condition was instead that $\mathbb E[M_t | \mathscr F_{t-1}] \fbox = M_{t-1} - \alpha$ (for all $t$), then you'd have a situation where $M_t + t \alpha$ was a genuine martingale, and you could use martingale tactics like the Optional Stopping Theorem to proceed. Without that level of specificity, the best you'll be able to hope for is *bounds* on things like $\mathbb E[\tau]$.

Edited to add: Even in the case where you can specify the expected drift, you might have to settle for bounds. You can get much cleaner results in cases when you know $M_{\tau} = -1$ almost surely (for instance) rather than just knowing that $M_{\tau} < 0$.